# Unity Button Navigation Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

First I will explain what I want to achieve.

This is a 2D game.
I have a world select menu which is basically a very wide image and I have an overlay canvas with two buttons for move left and move right, these buttons are on the far left and far right of the screen. When the right button is pressed the camera is moved right by 1920 pixels which shows each levelworld in turn.

Now I want a world select button on each of these sections so I have placed a second canvas set to worldview. and then i have placed panels on each section each with a button in. The panels are set to not interactive (via a canvasgroup) and are made interactive when brought into view.

My issue is that if I am on say the left button and I press right it does not navigate to the middle button, it navigates to the right button, then if I press right again it navigates to the centre button.....

How do I get it to navigate naturally from left to centre to right bearing in mind that the centre button is whichever one is currently visible

Comment: Do you have any example code? So your world select button is always in its own worldview canvas and each one of your level images has its own world select button/canvas, which when you move right and left your overlay canvas sits on top?

Comment: That is correct although there is just one world canvas with panels for each world select button.

Comment: I've been really busy so i haven't been able to answer. How is your project going? Still have this same issue?

Comment: Yes thanks. I did away with the left and right buttons and subscribed to the selected event instead. When the button gets selected it moves the camera to its position.